# Text instead of dotted line if text is not blank

Tags: datatool

I use `datatool`.

And I have this flow:

- if text A or text B is blank, a dotted line is displayed
- if text A
  or text B is not blank, a dotted line is removed and text A/text B is
  displayed

My Minimal Working Example:

```
 \RequirePackage{filecontents}

    \begin{filecontents*}{file.tex}

    No,TextA,TextB
    1,a1,b1
    2,,b2
    3,a2,
    4,,
    5,a5,b5

\end{filecontents*}

    \documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
    \usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
    \usepackage{filecontents}
    \usepackage{datatool}
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage{xparse}
    \usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \tcbset{colframe=blue!75!black,colback=white}


    \DTLloaddb{file}{file.tex}
    \begin{document}

    \DTLforeach*
      {file}% Database
      {\No=No,\TextA=TextA,\TextB=TextB}
      {%
       \begin{tcolorbox}[width=3cm, height=2cm]

      \No \quad \\
      ..........\TextA \quad \\
      ..........\TextB
       \end{tcolorbox}
    %   \newpage
      }

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\DTLifnullorempty` to test if the entry is empty or not.

*Edit:* To test for value 0, use `\DTLifeq`.

```
 \RequirePackage{filecontents}

    \begin{filecontents*}{file.tex}
    No,TextA,TextB
    1,a1,b1
    2,,b2
    3,a2,
    4,,
    5,0,b2
    6,a2,0
    7,0,0
\end{filecontents*}

    \documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
    \usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
    \usepackage{filecontents}
    \usepackage{datatool}
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage{xparse}
    \usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \tcbset{colframe=blue!75!black,colback=white}


    \DTLloaddb{file}{file.tex}
    \begin{document}

    \DTLforeach*
      {file}% Database
      {\No=No,\TextA=TextA,\TextB=TextB}
      {%
       \begin{tcolorbox}[width=3cm, height=2cm]
         \No\newline
         \DTLifnullorempty{\TextA}{..........}{\DTLifeq{\TextA}{0}{..........}{\TextA}}\newline
         \DTLifnullorempty{\TextB}{..........}{\DTLifeq{\TextB}{0}{..........}{\TextB}}
       \end{tcolorbox}
    %   \newpage
      }

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. It works. And i want same if text A = 0 or null or empty? how rewrite this code "\DTLifnullorempty"

Comment: @latexforti The right macro is `\DTLifeq`, see my edit.